# I want to run a formula from bloomberg in 15 minute intervals and then store the values to create a line chart

Tags: python, automation, finance, quantitative-finance

I have a formula from Bloomberg that I want to be executed every 15 minutes. I want this code to run every day from 9 am to 4 pm in 15-minute intervals. After each iteration, I want these values to be stored somewhere so that I can eventually create a continuous intraday line chart. I have tried to create scheduled runs, but it just prints my values instead.

I've tried to create a schedule that will run every 15 minutes at this point. I want this to print the datapull_final code that contains my value. Every 15 minutes, this should be updated along with the market.

```
import sched, time
from xbbg import blp
import datetime
import schedule

today = datetime.datetime.now().ctime() 

def action():
    datapull = blp.bdp(tickers='BBG000BBV9N3 FIGI', flds=['YAS_YLD_SPREAD'])
    datapull_final = round(datapull.yas_yld_spread[0], 2)
    print(datapull_final)
    
# Set up scheduler
s = sched.scheduler(time.localtime, time.sleep)
# Schedule when you want the action to occur
s.enterabs(time.strptime(today), 900, action)
# Block until the action has been run
s.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sched, time
from xbbg import blp
import datetime
import pandas as pd

spreads = pd.DataFrame()

def action():
    global spreads
    datapull = blp.bdp('LQD US EQUITY', 'YAS_YLD_SPREAD')
    spreads = pd.concat([spreads, datapull])

action()

# Set up scheduler
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

while True:
    # Get the current time
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    # Check if the current time is between 9am and 4pm
    if 4 <= now.hour < 16:
        # Schedule when you want the action to occur
        next_run = time.time() + 900
        s.enterabs(next_run, 1, action)

        # Countdown timer
        while time.time() < next_run:
            time_left = int(next_run - time.time())
            print(f"Current Value: {spreads['yas_yld_spread'].round(2).values[-1]} | Time until next run: {round(time_left/60,2)} minutes", end='\r', flush=True)
            time.sleep(1)

        # Run the scheduled events
        s.run()
    else:
        print("It's not between 9am and 4pm. Waiting...")
        time.sleep(60)
```